# Can Firebase Functions Cache by Querystring Parameter? #askfirebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am testing a service that sends events to a Http trigger function, the event type is in the query string

> eventType=answer
>
> eventType=incomingcall

Is there an option to cache only the "incomingcall" eventType and not the "answer" eventType?

Nothing mentioned in the [firebase hosting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#setting_cache_control) but in [Goggle cloud functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#query_string_whitelist) there is an option for query string whitelist and blacklist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second doc you linked to is not for Google Cloud Functions, it's for Cloud CDN, which is a different CDN than the kind provided by Firebase Hosting.

Firebase Hosting will cache the output of Cloud Functions when using a rewrite rules to proxy the request, but it's your responsibility to set the cache headers in the response as shown in the first document you linked.  If you only want to cache the results of some request, you can control that logic in your function.

Comment: What about cache by a single query parameter even if other parameters and values are different to still return the same response from cache, like the query string whitelist in the CDN doc?

Comment: Like Michael Bligh says in his answer here, the entire query string is used to determine uniqueness of a response being cached.

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Functions that are integrated with Firebase Hosting consider different query parameters to be entirely different URLs for the purposes of caching. So yes, they will be cached separately and can have different `Cache-Control` headers set on them.